# Value Error in SVM classifier fit function

Tags: python, svm

I was trying to fit SVM into my training set and I have split my data into 80-20.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 0)
```

When I was running my code, I got the following error.

```
classifier = SVC(kernel = 'linear', random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-1017b9d39c40> in <module>()
  1 from sklearn.svm import SVC
  2 classifier = SVC(kernel = 'linear', random_state = 0)
----> 3 classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)


167     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
168                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 169         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
170 
171 
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

Can someone please tell me what was wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share a snapshot of your X_train and y_train ? I suspect that you are using a classifier with a continuous target variable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.